# Convert a list to a tree

Tags: swift, list, tree

I have an api returning a list of categories, which should really be a tree. Each item in the list looks like this:

```
struct ListCategory {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let parent: Int?
}
```

and I need it to be in a tree, something like this:

```
struct TreeCategory {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let children: [TreeCategory]
}
```

The list is unsorted, and more annoyingly, is un-sortable - i.e. a lower id for a category doesn't mean it will be higher in the tree (the tree was edited after it was created).

What's a good algorithm to do this? I'm expecting the list to contain about 50 items, so code clarity is at least as important as performance for me.

I have an idea, but this looks like the kind of problem there is a clever solution to :)

Options I've considered:

- Change the api. Ideally, sure, but I can't do this.
- Just use a library. It's an option, but it seems like overkill for just one operation in my whole app.

Answer (score 0):

For this algorithm you're going to need reference types so make your resulting Node data type a class:

```
class Node {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let parentId: Int?

    var children: [Node] = []

    init(name: String, id: Int, parentId: Int?) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.parentId = parentId
    }
}
```

Now when constructing the tree, we're going to create a dictionary where all of the children are grouped according to the parentId. If the parentId is nil, we have the root node, so let's just use the value -1 as the key for the root so we can store it in the dictionary. Once our dictionary is constructed we just need to associate each parent node with it's children.

```
struct Tree {

    var root: Node?

    init(nodes: [Node]) {
        let groups = Dictionary(grouping: nodes) { node -> Int in
            return node.parentId ?? -1
        }
        groups.forEach { pair in
            guard pair.key != -1 else { return }
            let parent = nodes.first { $0.id == pair.key }
            parent?.children = pair.value
        }
        root = groups[-1]?.first
    }
}
```

The usage is quite simple:

```
let nodes = [
    Node(name: "a", id: 0, parentId: nil),
    Node(name: "b", id: 1, parentId: 0),
    Node(name: "c", id: 2, parentId: 0),
    Node(name: "d", id: 3, parentId: 1),
    Node(name: "e", id: 4, parentId: 1),
    Node(name: "f", id: 5, parentId: 2),
    Node(name: "g", id: 6, parentId: 2),
]

let tree = Tree(nodes: nodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative API to to this, code is commented for simplicity. The `Node` struct has a direct link to its parent instead of of `parentId`. This makes the code more robust as there is only one source of truth for the `id`.

For instance without this if you change a node `id` you would have to reflect this change in children, but with a direct reference it is not necessary.

I provided a sample API to directly retrieve `parentId` in a correct way.

I did not optimise this code but I think that this would be fast, especially if you are planning to store around fifty items.

There are two Swift approaches that I really like in this:

- The use of KeyPath during the dict grouping that makes the code clear and concise
- The recursive function that is well suited for tree structures and self-explanatory

Here is the code, you can test and explore it in a Xcode playground:

```
// Your old struct
struct ListCategory {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let parentId: Int?
}

extension ListCategory {
    // Helper function to convert to new structure
    func toNode(parent: Node? = nil, children: [Node] = []) -> Node {
        Node(name: name, id: id, parent: parent, children: children)
    }
}

// New struct to store a category
class Node {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
    var children: [Node] = []  // You can make this [Node?]
    // if you are planning to remove nodes at some points

    // Weak var to avoid retain cycles
    weak var parent: Node?

    init(name: String, id: Int, parent: Node? = nil, children: [Node] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children
    }
}

// Exemple of API you can build
extension Node {
  var parentId: Int? { parent?.id }
}

class Tree {
    var root: Node?

    init(categories: [ListCategory]) {
        // Group categories by parent id
        let categoriesByParentId = Dictionary(grouping: categories, by: \.parentId)

        // Convert Categories to Nodes
        let nodesByParentId = categoriesByParentId.mapValues { categories in
            categories.map { $0.toNode() }
        }

        // Check if only 1 root node
        guard let rootNode = nodesByParentId[nil], rootNode.count == 1 else {
            // Handle error here...
            fatalError()
        }

        // Create and assign the root node
        root = rootNode.first

        // Recursive function to build the tree
        func buildTree(node: Node?) {
            // For the current node find its children
            // If no children its a leaf node (bottom of the tree), just return
            guard let children = nodesByParentId[node?.id] else { return }

            // Else, link the parent to their children
            node?.children = children

            // for each child
            for child in children {
                // Link the child to its parent
                child.parent = node

                // Continue building the tree from this node
                buildTree(node: child)
            }
        }

        // Start to build from the root node
        buildTree(node: root)
    }
}

// Main
let categories = [
    ListCategory(name: "hello", id: 0, parentId: nil),
    ListCategory(name: "world", id: 1, parentId: 0),
    ListCategory(name: "toto", id: 2, parentId: 0),
    ListCategory(name: "bob", id: 3, parentId: 1),
]

let tree = Tree(categories: categories)
```